# Tracking 1st generation package upload progress via SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package

At early days of our project (about five years ago) we implemented package upload script which is simply clicking through web UI using headless browser in background. After upload was triggered we parsed also any messages displayed on a web page related to status progress, e.g. `Queued..., Analyzing..., Running Tests (132/4534)` etc., and the same is about parsing any error messages which may pop up in the end in case of tests failures.

As result we got a pretty decent CI job which automates upload process from start to end reporting detail status along the way and errors in the end, so you don't need even to log in to packaging org to check anything.

And now we are trying to re-implement the same for our 1st generation managed package but using DX to get rid of this web scrapping job, and do it in a more civilized way.

We are mainly relying on the following 2 DX commands to trigger package upload and monitor status periodically:
`sfdx force:package1:version:create` and `sfdx force:package1:version:create:get`

But as it turns out we cannot get back the same level of status details while upload is in progress. The only thing dx commands report back is `status=IN-PROGRESS`, which gives us no clue at which stage upload process is currently in, how many tests have already been executed etc. As in our case, package upload takes up to 6 hours to complete, so watching at `IN-PROGRESS` message for all that time is kind of disappointing.

We would like to achieve the same level of status details reported back as with web scrapping approach. Is there something we are missing here, e.g. some magical dx command or table to query on our own to get similar status messages that web UI shows us?

Any help would be appreciated